# Win7 Task Schedular Event's Security Options when accessing SQLServer on Network

Tags: c#, sql-server, windows-task-scheduler

I have developed a c# executable that accesses a SQL Server on the domain using SQL Server authentication.  It will be scheduled to run once a day via the Windows Task Scheduler.  It is to be run whether the user is logged on or not.  What security options / accounts should be used?

Comment: depends on the security roles that your C# code needs... what is your application doing?

Comment: If you are using SQL Server Authentication then it doesn't matter the windows user. You will want the task to run even if someone isn't logged on. What will matter is if your application is accessing files, folders ..etc that would require it to run under a user that has access to those resources.

Comment: The process is reading two views from the sqlServer, Creating an XML file from the dataset in memory, then creating the file on an FTPS server.  Any information gets sent to the log.  Nothing gets written to the host machine.

Comment: The process does access a control file, it is kept in a subdirectory under the c:\Program Files(x86)\'Program Directory'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The process had been hanging up and wasn't going anywhere.  I had thought it had something to do with the SQLServer portion, or perhaps the FTPS server.  Things that I thought would have permissions problems.  Come to find out, I was attempting to write an entry to the event log; I had coded it such that if the 'Source' was not there, to create it.  Running as SYSTEM didn't have permissions to create the EventSource.  I ended up writing to a Log file and the problem was solved.